# splitting a list into sublists based on the element immediately before another

Tags: python

I have a list of flight details that I scraped from google flights:

```
result = ['12:10\u202fPM', ' – ', '5:20\u202fPM', 'AirAsia X', '3 hr 10 min', 'SYD–AKL', 'Nonstop', '139 kg CO2', 'Avg emissions', 'A$540', 'round trip', '7:50\u202fPM', ' – ', '1:00\u202fAM+1', 'Jetstar', '3 hr 10 min', 'SYD–AKL', 'Nonstop', '139 kg CO2', 'Avg emissions', 'A$669', 'round trip', '11:45\u202fAM', ' – ', '4:45\u202fPM', 'Separate tickets booked together', 'Air New Zealand', '3 hr', 'SYD–AKL', 'Nonstop', '170 kg CO2', '+16% emissions', 'A$697', 'round trip', '7:25\u202fAM', ' – ', '12:35\u202fPM', 'Separate tickets booked together', 'QantasAir Tahiti Nui', '3 hr 10 min', 'SYD–AKL', 'Nonstop', '146 kg CO2', 'Avg emissions', 'A$707', 'round trip', '11:15\u202fAM', ' – ', '4:20\u202fPM', 'LATAMQantas', '3 hr 5 min', 'SYD–AKL', 'Nonstop', '134 kg CO2', '-8% emissions', 'A$718', 'round trip', 'Price insights', 'Prices are currently low — A$463 cheaper than usual for your search', 'View price history', 'Other departing flights', '9:55\u202fAM', ' – ', '3:05\u202fPM', 'Separate tickets booked together', 'Air New Zealand', '3 hr 10 min', 'SYD–AKL', 'Nonstop', '128 kg CO2', '-12% emissions', 'A$697', 'round trip', '3:30\u202fPM', ' – ', '8:30\u202fPM', 'Separate tickets booked together', 'Air New Zealand', '3 hr', 'SYD–AKL', 'Nonstop', '128 kg CO2', '-12% emissions', 'A$697', 'round trip', '7:15\u202fPM', ' – ', '12:25\u202fAM+1', 'Separate tickets booked together', 'Air New Zealand', '3 hr 10 min', 'SYD–AKL', 'Nonstop', '128 kg CO2', '-12% emissions', 'A$697', 'round trip', '7:15\u202fPM', ' – ', '12:25\u202fAM+1', 'Separate tickets booked together', 'QantasAir Tahiti Nui', '3 hr 10 min', 'SYD–AKL', 'Nonstop', '146 kg CO2', 'Avg emissions', 'A$707', 'round trip', '11:15\u202fAM', ' – ', '4:25\u202fPM', 'Separate tickets booked together', 'QantasAir Tahiti Nui', '3 hr 10 min', 'SYD–AKL', 'Nonstop', '151 kg CO2', 'Avg emissions', 'A$727', 'round trip', '5:35\u202fPM', ' – ', '10:45\u202fPM', 'Separate tickets booked together', 'QantasAir Tahiti Nui', '3 hr 10 min', 'SYD–AKL', 'Nonstop', '146 kg CO2', 'Avg emissions', 'A$727', 'round trip', '9:05\u202fAM', ' – ', '2:15\u202fPM', 'Separate tickets booked together', 'QantasAir Tahiti Nui', '3 hr 10 min', 'SYD–AKL', 'Nonstop', '146 kg CO2', 'Avg emissions', 'A$748', 'round trip', '9:40\u202fAM', ' – ', '2:50\u202fPM', 'Separate tickets booked together', 'Qantas', '3 hr 10 min', 'SYD–AKL', 'Nonstop', '140 kg CO2', 'Avg emissions', 'A$748', 'round trip']
```

I want to clean this list by extracting individual flight details. I can see that one way to do it is by splitting the list based on the element immediately before the ' - ' element.

I have managed to split the list based on the ' - ' element, but I'm not sure how to do it based on the element immediately before it:

```
import itertools
y = [list(x[1]) for x in itertools.groupby(result, lambda x: x == ' – ') if not x[0]]
print(y)

[['12:10\u202fPM'], ['5:20\u202fPM', 'AirAsia X', '3 hr 10 min', 'SYD–AKL', 'Nonstop', '139 kg CO2', 'Avg emissions', 'A$540', 'round trip', '7:50\u202fPM'], ['1:00\u202fAM+1', 'Jetstar', '3 hr 10 min', 'SYD–AKL', 'Nonstop', '139 kg CO2', 'Avg emissions', 'A$669', 'round trip', '11:45\u202fAM'], ['4:45\u202fPM', 'Separate tickets booked together', 'Air New Zealand', '3 hr', 'SYD–AKL', 'Nonstop', '170 kg CO2', '+16% emissions', 'A$697', 'round trip', '7:25\u202fAM'], ['12:35\u202fPM', 'Separate tickets booked together', 'QantasAir Tahiti Nui', '3 hr 10 min', 'SYD–AKL', 'Nonstop', '146 kg CO2', 'Avg emissions', 'A$707', 'round trip', '11:15\u202fAM'], ['4:20\u202fPM', 'LATAMQantas', '3 hr 5 min', 'SYD–AKL', 'Nonstop', '134 kg CO2', '-8% emissions', 'A$718', 'round trip', 'Price insights', 'Prices are currently low — A$463 cheaper than usual for your search', 'View price history', 'Other departing flights', '9:55\u202fAM'], ['3:05\u202fPM', 'Separate tickets booked together', 'Air New Zealand', '3 hr 10 min', 'SYD–AKL', 'Nonstop', '128 kg CO2', '-12% emissions', 'A$697', 'round trip', '3:30\u202fPM'], ['8:30\u202fPM', 'Separate tickets booked together', 'Air New Zealand', '3 hr', 'SYD–AKL', 'Nonstop', '128 kg CO2', '-12% emissions', 'A$697', 'round trip', '7:15\u202fPM'], ['12:25\u202fAM+1', 'Separate tickets booked together', 'Air New Zealand', '3 hr 10 min', 'SYD–AKL', 'Nonstop', '128 kg CO2', '-12% emissions', 'A$697', 'round trip', '7:15\u202fPM'], ['12:25\u202fAM+1', 'Separate tickets booked together', 'QantasAir Tahiti Nui', '3 hr 10 min', 'SYD–AKL', 'Nonstop', '146 kg CO2', 'Avg emissions', 'A$707', 'round trip', '11:15\u202fAM'], ['4:25\u202fPM', 'Separate tickets booked together', 'QantasAir Tahiti Nui', '3 hr 10 min', 'SYD–AKL', 'Nonstop', '151 kg CO2', 'Avg emissions', 'A$727', 'round trip', '5:35\u202fPM'], ['10:45\u202fPM', 'Separate tickets booked together', 'QantasAir Tahiti Nui', '3 hr 10 min', 'SYD–AKL', 'Nonstop', '146 kg CO2', 'Avg emissions', 'A$727', 'round trip', '9:05\u202fAM'], ['2:15\u202fPM', 'Separate tickets booked together', 'QantasAir Tahiti Nui', '3 hr 10 min', 'SYD–AKL', 'Nonstop', '146 kg CO2', 'Avg emissions', 'A$748', 'round trip', '9:40\u202fAM'], ['2:50\u202fPM', 'Separate tickets booked together', 'Qantas', '3 hr 10 min', 'SYD–AKL', 'Nonstop', '140 kg CO2', 'Avg emissions', 'A$748', 'round trip']]
```

Expected result:

```
[['12:10\u202fPM', '5:20\u202fPM', 'AirAsia X', '3 hr 10 min', 'SYD–AKL', 'Nonstop', '139 kg CO2', 'Avg emissions', 'A$540', 'round trip'], ['7:50\u202fPM', '1:00\u202fAM+1', 'Jetstar', '3 hr 10 min', 'SYD–AKL', 'Nonstop', '139 kg CO2', 'Avg emissions', 'A$669', 'round trip'], ['11:45\u202fAM', '4:45\u202fPM', 'Separate tickets booked together', 'Air New Zealand', '3 hr', 'SYD–AKL', 'Nonstop', '170 kg CO2', '+16% emissions', 'A$697', 'round trip'], ['7:25\u202fAM', '12:35\u202fPM', 'Separate tickets booked together', 'QantasAir Tahiti Nui', '3 hr 10 min', 'SYD–AKL', 'Nonstop', '146 kg CO2', 'Avg emissions', 'A$707', 'round trip'], ['11:15\u202fAM', '4:20\u202fPM', 'LATAMQantas', '3 hr 5 min', 'SYD–AKL', 'Nonstop', '134 kg CO2', '-8% emissions', 'A$718', 'round trip', 'Price insights', 'Prices are currently low — A$463 cheaper than usual for your search', 'View price history', 'Other departing flights'], ['9:55\u202fAM', '3:05\u202fPM', 'Separate tickets booked together', 'Air New Zealand', '3 hr 10 min', 'SYD–AKL', 'Nonstop', '128 kg CO2', '-12% emissions', 'A$697', 'round trip'], ['3:30\u202fPM', '8:30\u202fPM', 'Separate tickets booked together', 'Air New Zealand', '3 hr', 'SYD–AKL', 'Nonstop', '128 kg CO2', '-12% emissions', 'A$697', 'round trip'], ['7:15\u202fPM', '12:25\u202fAM+1', 'Separate tickets booked together', 'Air New Zealand', '3 hr 10 min', 'SYD–AKL', 'Nonstop', '128 kg CO2', '-12% emissions', 'A$697', 'round trip'], ['7:15\u202fPM', '12:25\u202fAM+1', 'Separate tickets booked together', 'QantasAir Tahiti Nui', '3 hr 10 min', 'SYD–AKL', 'Nonstop', '146 kg CO2', 'Avg emissions', 'A$707', 'round trip'], ['11:15\u202fAM', '4:25\u202fPM', 'Separate tickets booked together', 'QantasAir Tahiti Nui', '3 hr 10 min', 'SYD–AKL', 'Nonstop', '151 kg CO2', 'Avg emissions', 'A$727', 'round trip'], ['5:35\u202fPM', '10:45\u202fPM', 'Separate tickets booked together', 'QantasAir Tahiti Nui', '3 hr 10 min', 'SYD–AKL', 'Nonstop', '146 kg CO2', 'Avg emissions', 'A$727', 'round trip'], ['9:05\u202fAM', '2:15\u202fPM', 'Separate tickets booked together', 'QantasAir Tahiti Nui', '3 hr 10 min', 'SYD–AKL', 'Nonstop', '146 kg CO2', 'Avg emissions', 'A$748', 'round trip'], ['9:40\u202fAM', '2:50\u202fPM', 'Separate tickets booked together', 'Qantas', '3 hr 10 min', 'SYD–AKL', 'Nonstop', '140 kg CO2', 'Avg emissions', 'A$748', 'round trip']]
```

Comment: post the expected result

Comment: `library(itertools)`?!

Comment: There is no (direct and sane) way to make `groupby` look at surrounding elements

Comment: This might be an XY problem - you're asking about what you think is a solution to a problem instead of asking about the problem. i.e. how to scrape the data of the flights. If you showed how you got that data, there might be a better way to get it to begin with. I doubt that all flights' data is just thrown like this all together...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```py
import itertools

mask = itertools.accumulate(result[min(len(result)-1, i+1)] == " – " for i in range(len(result)))

out = [list(v for _, v in g if v != ' – ') for _, g in itertools.groupby(zip(mask, result), lambda x: x[0])]
print(out)
```

Prints:

```py
[
    [
        "12:10\u202fPM",
        "5:20\u202fPM",
        "AirAsia X",
        "3 hr 10 min",
        "SYD–AKL",
        "Nonstop",
        "139 kg CO2",
        "Avg emissions",
        "A$540",
        "round trip",
    ],
    [
        "7:50\u202fPM",
        "1:00\u202fAM+1",
        "Jetstar",
        "3 hr 10 min",
        "SYD–AKL",
        "Nonstop",
        "139 kg CO2",
        "Avg emissions",
        "A$669",
        "round trip",
    ],

...
```

Answer (score 1):

`'round trip'` phrase is suited to be a split factor (as each resulting sublist ends with it). Use the following approach:

```
from itertools import groupby

result = ['12:10\u202fPM', ' – ', '5:20\u202fPM', 'AirAsia X', '3 hr 10 min', 'SYD–AKL', 'Nonstop', '139 kg CO2', 'Avg emissions', 'A$540', 'round trip', '7:50\u202fPM', ' – ', '1:00\u202fAM+1', 'Jetstar', '3 hr 10 min', 'SYD–AKL', 'Nonstop', '139 kg CO2', 'Avg emissions', 'A$669', 'round trip', '11:45\u202fAM', ' – ', '4:45\u202fPM', 'Separate tickets booked together', 'Air New Zealand', '3 hr', 'SYD–AKL', 'Nonstop', '170 kg CO2', '+16% emissions', 'A$697', 'round trip', '7:25\u202fAM', ' – ', '12:35\u202fPM', 'Separate tickets booked together', 'QantasAir Tahiti Nui', '3 hr 10 min', 'SYD–AKL', 'Nonstop', '146 kg CO2', 'Avg emissions', 'A$707', 'round trip', '11:15\u202fAM', ' – ', '4:20\u202fPM', 'LATAMQantas', '3 hr 5 min', 'SYD–AKL', 'Nonstop', '134 kg CO2', '-8% emissions', 'A$718', 'round trip', 'Price insights', 'Prices are currently low — A$463 cheaper than usual for your search', 'View price history', 'Other departing flights', '9:55\u202fAM', ' – ', '3:05\u202fPM', 'Separate tickets booked together', 'Air New Zealand', '3 hr 10 min', 'SYD–AKL', 'Nonstop', '128 kg CO2', '-12% emissions', 'A$697', 'round trip', '3:30\u202fPM', ' – ', '8:30\u202fPM', 'Separate tickets booked together', 'Air New Zealand', '3 hr', 'SYD–AKL', 'Nonstop', '128 kg CO2', '-12% emissions', 'A$697', 'round trip', '7:15\u202fPM', ' – ', '12:25\u202fAM+1', 'Separate tickets booked together', 'Air New Zealand', '3 hr 10 min', 'SYD–AKL', 'Nonstop', '128 kg CO2', '-12% emissions', 'A$697', 'round trip', '7:15\u202fPM', ' – ', '12:25\u202fAM+1', 'Separate tickets booked together', 'QantasAir Tahiti Nui', '3 hr 10 min', 'SYD–AKL', 'Nonstop', '146 kg CO2', 'Avg emissions', 'A$707', 'round trip', '11:15\u202fAM', ' – ', '4:25\u202fPM', 'Separate tickets booked together', 'QantasAir Tahiti Nui', '3 hr 10 min', 'SYD–AKL', 'Nonstop', '151 kg CO2', 'Avg emissions', 'A$727', 'round trip', '5:35\u202fPM', ' – ', '10:45\u202fPM', 'Separate tickets booked together', 'QantasAir Tahiti Nui', '3 hr 10 min', 'SYD–AKL', 'Nonstop', '146 kg CO2', 'Avg emissions', 'A$727', 'round trip', '9:05\u202fAM', ' – ', '2:15\u202fPM', 'Separate tickets booked together', 'QantasAir Tahiti Nui', '3 hr 10 min', 'SYD–AKL', 'Nonstop', '146 kg CO2', 'Avg emissions', 'A$748', 'round trip', '9:40\u202fAM', ' – ', '2:50\u202fPM', 'Separate tickets booked together', 'Qantas', '3 hr 10 min', 'SYD–AKL', 'Nonstop', '140 kg CO2', 'Avg emissions', 'A$748', 'round trip']
flights = [[*gr, 'round trip'] 
           for k, gr in filter(lambda x: x[0],  # filter positive groups
                               groupby((i for i in result if i != ' – '), 
                                       key=lambda x: x != 'round trip'))]
print(flights)
```

---

```
[['12:10\u202fPM', '5:20\u202fPM', 'AirAsia X', '3 hr 10 min', 'SYD–AKL', 'Nonstop', '139 kg CO2', 'Avg emissions', 'A$540', 'round trip'],
 ['7:50\u202fPM', '1:00\u202fAM+1', 'Jetstar', '3 hr 10 min', 'SYD–AKL', 'Nonstop', '139 kg CO2', 'Avg emissions', 'A$669', 'round trip'],
 ['11:45\u202fAM', '4:45\u202fPM', 'Separate tickets booked together', 'Air New Zealand', '3 hr', 'SYD–AKL', 'Nonstop', '170 kg CO2', '+16% emissions', 'A$697', 'round trip'],
 ['7:25\u202fAM', '12:35\u202fPM', 'Separate tickets booked together', 'QantasAir Tahiti Nui', '3 hr 10 min', 'SYD–AKL', 'Nonstop', '146 kg CO2', 'Avg emissions', 'A$707', 'round trip'],
 ['11:15\u202fAM', '4:20\u202fPM', 'LATAMQantas', '3 hr 5 min', 'SYD–AKL', 'Nonstop', '134 kg CO2', '-8% emissions', 'A$718', 'round trip'],
 ['Price insights', 'Prices are currently low — A$463 cheaper than usual for your search', 'View price history', 'Other departing flights', '9:55\u202fAM', '3:05\u202fPM', 'Separate tickets booked together', 'Air New Zealand', '3 hr 10 min', 'SYD–AKL', 'Nonstop', '128 kg CO2', '-12% emissions', 'A$697', 'round trip'],
 ['3:30\u202fPM', '8:30\u202fPM', 'Separate tickets booked together', 'Air New Zealand', '3 hr', 'SYD–AKL', 'Nonstop', '128 kg CO2', '-12% emissions', 'A$697', 'round trip'],
 ['7:15\u202fPM', '12:25\u202fAM+1', 'Separate tickets booked together', 'Air New Zealand', '3 hr 10 min', 'SYD–AKL', 'Nonstop', '128 kg CO2', '-12% emissions', 'A$697', 'round trip'],
 ['7:15\u202fPM', '12:25\u202fAM+1', 'Separate tickets booked together', 'QantasAir Tahiti Nui', '3 hr 10 min', 'SYD–AKL', 'Nonstop', '146 kg CO2', 'Avg emissions', 'A$707', 'round trip'],
 ['11:15\u202fAM', '4:25\u202fPM', 'Separate tickets booked together', 'QantasAir Tahiti Nui', '3 hr 10 min', 'SYD–AKL', 'Nonstop', '151 kg CO2', 'Avg emissions', 'A$727', 'round trip'],
 ['5:35\u202fPM', '10:45\u202fPM', 'Separate tickets booked together', 'QantasAir Tahiti Nui', '3 hr 10 min', 'SYD–AKL', 'Nonstop', '146 kg CO2', 'Avg emissions', 'A$727', 'round trip'],
 ['9:05\u202fAM', '2:15\u202fPM', 'Separate tickets booked together', 'QantasAir Tahiti Nui', '3 hr 10 min', 'SYD–AKL', 'Nonstop', '146 kg CO2', 'Avg emissions', 'A$748', 'round trip'],
 ['9:40\u202fAM', '2:50\u202fPM', 'Separate tickets booked together', 'Qantas', '3 hr 10 min', 'SYD–AKL', 'Nonstop', '140 kg CO2', 'Avg emissions', 'A$748', 'round trip']]
```

Comment: One of the elements in the expected output ends with 'Other departing flights'

Comment: The term `round trip` indicates that the field is for the type of flight. i.e. `one way` could be an option. So while it might solve the current example it's not going to be a good general solution

Answer (score 0):

Without `itertools` you can use a double comprehension:

```
splitter_idx = [i for i, el in enumerate(result) if el == ' – '] + [len(result)+1]
items = [[result[idx-1]] + result[idx+1:splitter_idx[i+1]-1] for i, idx in enumerate(splitter_idx[:-1])]
```

Output:

```
[
['12:10\u202fPM', '5:20\u202fPM', 'AirAsia X', '3 hr 10 min', 'SYD–AKL', 'Nonstop', '139 kg CO2', 'Avg emissions', 'A$540', 'round trip'],
['7:50\u202fPM', '1:00\u202fAM+1', 'Jetstar', '3 hr 10 min', 'SYD–AKL', 'Nonstop', '139 kg CO2', 'Avg emissions', 'A$669', 'round trip'],
['11:45\u202fAM', '4:45\u202fPM', 'Separate tickets booked together', 'Air New Zealand', '3 hr', 'SYD–AKL', 'Nonstop', '170 kg CO2', '+16% emissions', 'A$697', 'round trip'],
['7:25\u202fAM', '12:35\u202fPM', 'Separate tickets booked together', 'QantasAir Tahiti Nui', '3 hr 10 min', 'SYD–AKL', 'Nonstop', '146 kg CO2', 'Avg emissions', 'A$707', 'round trip'],
['11:15\u202fAM', '4:20\u202fPM', 'LATAMQantas', '3 hr 5 min', 'SYD–AKL', 'Nonstop', '134 kg CO2', '-8% emissions', 'A$718', 'round trip', 'Price insights', 'Prices are currently low — A$463 cheaper than usual for your search', 'View price history', 'Other departing flights'],
['9:55\u202fAM', '3:05\u202fPM', 'Separate tickets booked together', 'Air New Zealand', '3 hr 10 min', 'SYD–AKL', 'Nonstop', '128 kg CO2', '-12% emissions', 'A$697', 'round trip'],
['3:30\u202fPM', '8:30\u202fPM', 'Separate tickets booked together', 'Air New Zealand', '3 hr', 'SYD–AKL', 'Nonstop', '128 kg CO2', '-12% emissions', 'A$697', 'round trip'],
['7:15\u202fPM', '12:25\u202fAM+1', 'Separate tickets booked together', 'Air New Zealand', '3 hr 10 min', 'SYD–AKL', 'Nonstop', '128 kg CO2', '-12% emissions', 'A$697', 'round trip'],
['7:15\u202fPM', '12:25\u202fAM+1', 'Separate tickets booked together', 'QantasAir Tahiti Nui', '3 hr 10 min', 'SYD–AKL', 'Nonstop', '146 kg CO2', 'Avg emissions', 'A$707', 'round trip'],
['11:15\u202fAM', '4:25\u202fPM', 'Separate tickets booked together', 'QantasAir Tahiti Nui', '3 hr 10 min', 'SYD–AKL', 'Nonstop', '151 kg CO2', 'Avg emissions', 'A$727', 'round trip'],
['5:35\u202fPM', '10:45\u202fPM', 'Separate tickets booked together', 'QantasAir Tahiti Nui', '3 hr 10 min', 'SYD–AKL', 'Nonstop', '146 kg CO2', 'Avg emissions', 'A$727', 'round trip'],
['9:05\u202fAM', '2:15\u202fPM', 'Separate tickets booked together', 'QantasAir Tahiti Nui', '3 hr 10 min', 'SYD–AKL', 'Nonstop', '146 kg CO2', 'Avg emissions', 'A$748', 'round trip'],
['9:40\u202fAM', '2:50\u202fPM', 'Separate tickets booked together', 'Qantas', '3 hr 10 min', 'SYD–AKL', 'Nonstop', '140 kg CO2', 'Avg emissions', 'A$748', 'round trip']
]
```